# sql. автозаполнение поля значением из другого

Tags: sql, postgresql

postgreSQL
Есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE payments(
pmId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
pmNumber CHAR(64) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
pmDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now(),
pmSum NUMERIC(9,2) NOT NULL CHECK(pmSum >= 0),
pmRest NUMERIC(9,2) NOT NULL CHECK(pmRest >= 0),
CONSTRAINT valid_pm_balance CHECK(pmSum-pmRest >= 0));
```

Подскажите как при запросе:

```
INSERT INTO payments (pmNumber,pmSum) VALUES (7,968)
```

Поле

> pmRest

Заполнялось так же как

> pmSum

Comment: сделать триггер на вставку в таблицу, который присвоит значение

Comment: Изменить запрос `INSERT INTO payments (pmNumber,pmSum,pmRest) VALUES (7,968,968)`

Comment: Запрос должен быть именно такого вида.

Comment: Почему? Вы не можете изменить запрос? Что-то  с дизайном не в порядке.

Comment: Пользователю не нужно знать о поле pmRest. Это поле предполагается изменять атоматически взависимости от запросов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION set_payment_rest_like_sum() RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
NEW.pmRest=NEW.pmSum;
return NEW;
END;
' LANGUAGE  plpgsql;

-- Создание триггера
CREATE TRIGGER set_rest
BEFORE INSERT ON payments FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_payment_rest_like_sum();
```